# disable assets precompile function in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I would like to disable assets precompile function in rails.
I am working on app where user can download the code, and I would like to avoid changeing the names of the css and js files in downloaded html file - so as the user can run the index.html and see everything.

Here is the app: 
http://impress-builder.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [The Assets Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) Guide.

> The asset pipeline is enabled by default. It can be disabled in
>   config/application.rb by putting this line inside the application
>   class definition:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Alternative Approach

```
config.assets.precompile
```

Is an array of files to be compiled. Swap it with an empty array to avoid precompilation.

```
# config/application.rb
# ...
config.assets.precompile = []
# ...
```