# Webpack not found error deploying rails application on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was attempting to deploy my Ruby on Rails app on Heroku when I faced below issue. (Of course, I've created and deployed on my local machine successfully.)

```
error Command "webpack" not found.
```

I don't have a clue about how to even know deploying any apps on heroku.
Of course I tried many ways and there was this error still now.
I referenced the posts that prevent precompiling of assets from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650621/heroku-upload-precompiling-assets-failed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935784/disable-assets-precompile-function-in-rails).

I followed all steps of above posts and it looked like to fix errors I faced. But I just spent my time. I've add this line `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` into config/application.rb and saw this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/512) because I found this article from Google with error commands. But these was not helpful.

I write my error:

```
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 1.77s.
remote:        I, [2020-03-23T10:31:49.843316 #3000]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0f0b4f66e4d0e7863926d7ab880dce89/public/assets/manifest-cadda289ef9c70eaa0879a36e6263cb33f7523a16b3ef862e0b8609cdc2bdab1.js
remote:        I, [2020-03-23T10:31:49.844161 #3000]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0f0b4f66e4d0e7863926d7ab880dce89/public/assets/manifest-cadda289ef9c70eaa0879a36e6263cb33f7523a16b3ef862e0b8609cdc2bdab1.js.gz
remote:        I, [2020-03-23T10:31:49.844830 #3000]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0f0b4f66e4d0e7863926d7ab880dce89/public/assets/application-d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f7fe8f768f6bbe005f6.css
remote:        I, [2020-03-23T10:31:49.845459 #3000]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_0f0b4f66e4d0e7863926d7ab880dce89/public/assets/application-d0ff5974b6aa52cf562bea5921840c032a860a91a3512f7fe8f768f6bbe005f6.css.gz
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        yarn run v1.22.4
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
remote:
remote:
remote:        error Command "webpack" not found.
remote:
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to evening-sierra-83681.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/evening-sierra-83681.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-sierra-83681.git'
```

Comment: Check if rails/webpacker is a dependency in package.json. Open a support ticket with Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JuanitoFatas